# How can I extend a dataset if I have only one file of a dynamic dataset?

Tags: network-structure

So, I want to extend a dataset, of which I have only file right now. I want to randomly generate values in the dataset so that, I can use it. How can I do it? How to make up a random dataset based on a previous file?

PS: A dynamic network dataset is one that has multiple files.

Edit : `http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon0302.html` . All information regarding the file is here. An excerpt of the dataset is as follows:

`# Amazon product co-purchaisng network from March 02 2003`

```
From to
 0  3
 0  4
 0  5
 1  0
 1  2
 1  4
 1  5   
 1  15
 2  0
 .........
```

It is based on Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought feature of the Amazon website. If a product i is frequently co-purchased with product j, the graph contains a directed edge from i to j.

Comment: What format is your file in? Please post an excerpt from your file. We can not answer if you don't post it and explain more.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, done. Have a look at it. :)

Comment: should be migrated to stats.SX

Comment: @philshem, this question is too old to be migrated.